# animated envelop with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am working at the moment on testimonials for family business website. And I am straggling to make it right. When you will mouse over a envelope, it should to move the envelope up, not all envelopes. And I have a problem with IE as well, even in new version of IE envelopes are not visible. I do not know why?

link to demo: http://fhukm.pl/testimonials1.html

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.33897.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="testimo">
<li class="envelope">
<div class="list">
<blockquote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</blockquote>
</div>
</li>
<li class="envelope">
<div class="list">
<blockquote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</blockquote>
</div>
</li>
<li class="envelope">
<div class="list">
<blockquote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</blockquote>
</div>
</li>
<li class="envelope">
<div class="list">
<blockquote>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX</blockquote>
</div>
</li> 
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```css
#testimo li {
margin-bottom:40px;
}
#testimo li p {
color:#666;
margin-top:5px;
font-size:18px;  
}
.hh2 p {
font-family:"Segoe Print";
font-size:17px !important;
}
.envelope {
 width:300px;
 height:150px;
 position:relative;
 padding: 120px 24px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition:1s;
 transition:1s;
 }
 .list {
 width:240px;
 height:150px;
 background:white;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888, 0 0 10px #888;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888, 0 0 10px #888;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888, 0 2px 8px #888;
 padding: 30px 20px 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 -webkit-transition:1s;
 position:absolute;
 top:100px;
 left:30px;
 z-index:2;
 -webkit-transition:0.8s;
 transition:0.8s;
 }
 .envtop {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 z-index:1;
 -webkit-transition:0.8s;
 transition:0.8s;
 }
 .envbot {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 z-index:3;
 -webkit-transition:0.8s;
 transition:0.8s;
 }
 .envani {
 -ms-transform:rotate(4deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);
 transform:rotate(4deg);
 top:0px;
 }
 .listani {
 top:60px;
 }
 .envshadow {
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
 z-index: 4;
 left: 0;
 }
 .gray .envtop, .gray .envbot {
 filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
 filter: gray;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

Javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('<img class="envtop" src="images/envtop.jpg" alt="Otwarta koperta."/>').prependTo('#testimo li');
  $('<img class="envbot" src="images/envbot.png" alt=" "/>').appendTo('#testimo li');
  $('<img class="envshadow" src="images/shadow.png" alt=" "/>').appendTo('#testimo li');

  $("#testimo :nth-child(4n+1)").addClass('gray');

  $('.envelope').mouseover(function() {
    $('.envtop').addClass('envani');
    $('.envbot').addClass('envani');
    $('.list').addClass('listani');
  });

  $(".envelope").mouseout(function() {
    $('.envtop').removeClass('envani');
    $('.envbot').removeClass('envani');
    $('.list').removeClass('listani');
  });

  $('.envelope').click(function() {
    $('.list')
     .css({top: 0})
     .delay(2000)
    .css({opacity: 0});

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mouse over you are changing all the classes and not the classes found in the parent class. A solution would be using `.find()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('').prependTo('#testimo li');
    $('').appendTo('#testimo li');
    $('').appendTo('#testimo li');

    $("#testimo :nth-child(4n+1)").addClass('gray');

    $('.envelope').mouseover(function () {
         $(this).find('.envtop').addClass('envani') 
         .end().find('.envbot').addClass('envani') 
      // .end() will return the selection to the first selector, in this case $(this)
         .end().find('.list').addClass('listani');
    });

    $(".envelope").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.envtop').removeClass('envani')
        .end().find('.envbot').removeClass('envani')
        .end().find('.list').removeClass('listani');
    });

    $('.envelope').click(function () {
        $(this).find('.list')
            .css({
            top: 0
        })
            .delay(2000)
            .css({
            opacity: 0
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Does anyone know why Internet Explorer would not show envelopes on the website?

Comment: @MarcinKilarski unfortunately not, as I have tried it in IE and the envelopes were showing. What version are you using?